# Login error when input wrong credentials " An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request

Tags: indexoutofrangeexception

These in ASP.NET application of which I am starting to learn. There is an error stating `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: UserId`.

Here is the code:

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 0;
        string roles = string.Empty;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
            {


                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();                                      
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
                roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
                con.Close();

            }
            switch (userId)
            {
                case -1:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                    break;
                default:
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                    string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                    {
                        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                    }
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet));
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Here is the Image to the error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmKAv.png)

Comment: Check reader["UserId"] the key exists or not..

Comment: @VishwaKumar  yes the key exists.